# Finding $4064569^{4513230} \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Can anyone help me with this?
Given the prime numbers $p=1039$ and $q=4283$, $n=qp$

Find: $4064569^{4513230} \pmod n$

Background:
We have learned about Fermat's Little Theorem and Chinese Reminder Theorem.

Comment: Use CRT: compute this enormous number mod $p$ and mod $q$.

Comment: the result is $$ \left( 59 \right)  \left( 68891 \right)  \left( 1942519 \right) $$

Comment: HINT: By FLT, $\gcd(4064569,n)=1\implies4064569^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod{n}$. And $\phi(n)$ is easy to calculate, as it is equal to $(p-1)(q-1)$.

Comment: @barakmanos That's Euler's theorem. FLT only applies to prime $n$.

Comment: @Arthur: Yeah, I always mix the two. I know that Euler's theorem is slightly more general, I just keep forgetting in what manner...

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Reduce the base modulo $p$ and modulo $q$ and the exponent modulo $p-1$ and $q-1$ (You apparantly did not have Euler's theorem). This is enough to find the residues easily in this case.

The solution of $x\equiv a\mod p \ ,\ x\equiv b\mod q$ is unique modulo $pq$.
The solution is the value $v$ with $0\le v<n$

Comment: The residue modulo $1039$ is $1$ and modulo $4283$ , it is $2^2=4$. The final result is $3293631$